# TypeError: Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. userStructs[userAddress].index = userIndex.push(userAddress) - 1;

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract UserCrud{
    struct userStruct{
        uint userAge;
        uint index;
        bytes32 userName;
        bytes32 userEmail;
    }
    mapping(address => userStruct) private userStructs;
    address[] private userIndex;

    function insertUser(
    address userAddress,
    uint userAge,
    bytes32 userName,
    bytes32 userEmail) public returns (uint index) {
        require(!isUser(userAddress));
        userStructs[userAddress].userAge = userAge;
        userStructs[userAddress].userName = userName;
        userStructs[userAddress].userEmail = userEmail;
        userStructs[userAddress].index = userIndex.push(userAddress) - 1; //error in this line
}
```

I got this code from an article regarding Solidity CRUD and was doing some modifications, but I'm facing an error as follows:

> TypeError: Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type
> uint256. userStructs[userAddress].index = userIndex.push(userAddress) - 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that since solc v0.6.0 `userIndex.push(userAddress)` no longer return the length as in previous versions.

You can fix the code with something like this

```
userIndex.push(userAddress);
userStructs[userAddress].index = userIndex.length - 1;
```

Comment: It removed the error but gave a 
Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning. 
bytes32 userEmail) public returns (uint index) {
which I can't remove. Sorry I'm new in solidity :(

Comment: @Raman In this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72486/unused-function-parameter-remove-or-comment-out-the-variable-name-to-silence-th you'll find a solution. In most cases it is faster to search the error message.